# Converting sql query to ActiveRecord Rails

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a location table in my database which contains location data of all the users of my system.

The table design is something like

```
 id| user_id| longitude| latitude| created_at|
```

I have an array of users. Now I want to select the latest(sorted according to created at) location of all these users.

I am able to figure out the sql query for same

```
SELECT * FROM   my_table
WHERE (user_id , created_at) IN (
                SELECT   user_id, MAX(created_at)
                FROM     my_table
                GROUP BY user_id
            )
AND user_id IN ('user1', 'user2', ... );
```

Now as I am working in Ruby On Rails, I  want to write this sql query to activerecord rails. Can anyone please help me with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will give the correct result:

```
MyModel.order(created_at: :desc).group(:user_id).distinct(:user_id)
```

If you want to generate the exact same query, this will do it:

```
MyModel.where("(user_id, created_at) IN (SELECT user_id, MAX(created_at) from my_table GROUP BY user_id)")
```

I think the subquery will probably not scale well with a large data set, but I understand if you just want to get it into rails and optimize later.

Comment: This is not generating the same sql query

SELECT DISTINCT "my_models".* FROM "my_models" GROUP BY "my_models"."user_id", "my_models"."id"  ORDER BY "my_models"."created_at" DESC

Comment: I added an edit that should reproduce the existing query exactly - let me know how it goes!

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a scope, and getting the same result in a slightly different way:

```
class UserLocation

  def self.latest_per_user
    where("user_locations.created_at = (select Max(ul2.created_at) from user_locations ul2 where ul2.user_id = user_locations.user_id)")
  end

end
```

Then you just use:

```
UserLocation.latest_per_user.where(:user_id => ['user1', 'user2'])
```

... to get the required data set.